# IE 8: background-size fix

Tags: css, xhtml, filter, width, background-image

I've tried to add background size to IE but it's not working at all:

HTML

```
<h2 id="news">Notícias <img src="white-marker.png" alt="" /></h2>
```

CSS:

```
div#content h2#news {
    background: url('../images/news-background.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    width: 90%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

What's wrong with the [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Make sure it is compatible refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie

Comment: Your suggestion works if you're not using border-radius...

Comment: As pointed out by @RSK, `background-size` doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: Ok, but as you can see in title, I need an IE 8 fix... Thank you guys.

Comment: Considering that only the very newest versions of most browsers (in some cases just the current beta versions) support `background-size`, you'll need a "fix" for more than just IE8. It's probably more sensible to rework your design, so that it doesn't need this. Or use an absolute positioning to place an image (not a background image) underneath the rest of the page.

Comment: No tengo idea. Just kidding.

Comment: did OP die? he's not active since 2011

Answer (score 147):

As posted by 'Dan' in a similar thread, there is a possible fix if you're not using a sprite:

[How do I make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie)

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

> However, this scales the entire image to fit in the allocated area. So
>   if your using a sprite, this may cause issues.

**Caution**
The filter has a flaw, any links inside the allocated area are no longer clickable.

Comment: The filter has a major flaw, in that it freezes any links inside the allocated area.

Comment: Also note the image path must be relative to the document rather than the CSS file.

Comment: its less than perfect but it gets the job done

Comment: is it possible to tell ie to scale the picture proportional..?

Comment: allegedly it should, as the sizing method is 'scale', but it seems to fail

Comment: If using this filter, I found that you can omit the -ms-filter option. Also, the URL should be relative to the HTML page and not the CSS file - I wasted a lot of time getting this to work, because I was doing it relative to CSS!

Comment: A fixed position div with 100% width and height rather than ptting this on the body will fix the broken links issue

Comment: Also, this method is not working with animated gifs

Comment: No, no, no. This filter doesn't keep the image proportions but instead the image the stretched to fill the container! It's the equivalent of "background-size: 100% 100%". Open this in IE8 to see it
http://jsfiddle.net/2VgjD/1/embedded/result/

Comment: this also doesn't work for pseudo-elements http://stackoverflow.com/a/10669986

Comment: using sprites and `background-size: cover` will always cause problems - that's not specific to this fix.

Comment: I am confused, where should we write this code?

Answer (score 89):

I created [jquery.backgroundSize.js](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js): a 1.5K jquery plugin that can be used as a IE8 fallback for "cover" and "contain" values. Have a look at the [demo](http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/).

Solving your problem could be as simple as:

```
$("h2#news").css({backgroundSize: "cover"});
```

Comment: This works incredible well! Thanks mate for saving my day!

Comment: Thanks, but this plugin seems to be having its own issues when applied to *body*.

Comment: Note that this plugin has apparently been superseded by https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Answer (score 20):

Also i have found another useful link. It is a background hack used like this

```
.selector { background-size: cover; -ms-behavior: url(/backgroundsize.min.htc); }
```

https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Comment: This was already mentioned by the author (Louis Rémi) in a previous answer.

Comment: But not in this question, Right!

Comment: Works perfect out of box!

Answer (score 12):

I use the filter solution above, for ie8.
However.. 
In order to solve the freezing links problem , do also the following:

```
background: no-repeat center center fixed\0/; /* IE8 HACK */
```

This has solved the frozen links problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed by @RSK IE8 doesn't support background-size. 
To figure out a way to deal with this, I used some IE specific hacks as showed here:

```
//IE8.0 Hack!
@media \0screen {
    .brand {
        background-image: url("./images/logo1.png");
        margin-top: 8px;
    }

    .navbar .brand {
        margin-left: -2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
}

//IE7.0 Hack!
*+html .brand {
    background-image: url("./images/logo1.png");
    margin-top: 8px;
}

*+html .navbar .brand {
    margin-left: -2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Using this I was able to change my logo image to a ugly resided picture. But the final result is fine. I suggest u try something like this.