# web app CSS navbar retina icons - How can I fit a 60x60 icon into a 30x30 background-image on IE7+8?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, jquery-mobile, retina-display, css

I'm trying to make a cross browser CSS nav-bar for mobile and desktop using Jquery Mobile.

I don't want to use media queries for retina/non-retina devices, so I'm basically trying to use a single hi-res CSS icon/sprite on all devices. The following works nicely except on IE7+8.

HTML

```
<span class="hasIcon">
   <span class="someText"></span>
   <span class="someBackground"></span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
 .hasIcon {
   display: inline-block;
   position: static;
   height: 30px; width: 30px;
   background-color: none;
   background: url("http://www.franckreich.de/x/IMG/gen/6060dummy.png") no-repeat;
           background-size: 30px 30px;
        -o-background-size: 30px 30px;
   -webkit-background-size: 30px 30px;
      -moz-background-size: 30px 30px;
       -ms-background-size: 30px 30px;
   }
```

JsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QTT4N/1/)

Of course this breaks in IE7+8, as backgrond-size is not supported...

My question: Does anybody have an idea how I can achieve this effect on IE7+8?

Solutions, I don't want to use:

- CSS Media Query for retina/non retina = miss out on good looks on desktop
- put retina/non-retina icons in single sprite & position accordingly = works so-so & serving bigger file

Curious to see if anybody can help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `filter`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QTT4N/3/

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
            src='http://www.franckreich.de/x/IMG/gen/6060dummy.png',
            sizingMethod='scale');
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Trying to get this done using sprites instead of a single image.

Comment: Then it **can't** be done using CSS in IE7/8. An ugly JavaScript/jQuery workaround would be possible.

Comment: mh. I wanted a CSS only solution, plus ugly scares me away :-) Trying some stuff, then I will woefully accept.

Comment: didn't work out. I guess I'm back to putting retina and non-retina icons in the same sprite. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [IE 8: background-size fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix).
Short answer: Use IE Filter. http://www.pziecina.com/design/turorial_demos/resize_background.php

Comment: Thanks. Trying this out. Let's see if it works with sprites aswell.