# Javascript: How to use modernizr to change background size to cover?

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

I used `Modernizr` for changing background size to `cover` to be cross-browser.
I want to have a fixed background position and size, when page size changed by user with zoom-out or site loaded with different resolution. Like this site: [www.australia.com](http://australia.com)

So I have imported the `Modernizr.js` into my `HTML` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Then I used `background-size` in my `style.css` file like this:

```
background-image:url(../../images/back.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top center;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

But the background is still resizable and the code not working, please tell me how can I use `Modernizr` in the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [Modernizr web site](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#howitworks)

> Modernizr is a small JavaScript library that detects the availability
>   of native implementations for next-generation web technologies

That means Modernizr is used **only** to check if the feature is available in the current browser, not to manipulate the DOM, or fix the CSS somehow, this is your responsibility. In that case you should use another CSS rule or JavaScript to perform the task you want based on what Modernizr told about that specific feature, like [fixing for the background-size in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix)

Comment: but I saw an example like this, that did it. www.australia.com this site background size not change while the page size changing.

Comment: So I am pretty sure it was using some other JS library together with Modernizr and may be you missed to notice

Comment: Please help me to find the library that do this

Comment: Do you have the URL for this example?

Comment: uow! sorry but this site has tons of JS besides `Modernizr` and it's gonna take too much to dive into that. All I can say is that it is  currently using an image as background, you can see it as the first element inside the `body` tag as the page background, which is something you can do if the `background-size` property is not available.

Comment: Thank you my friend, I know that this site uses a background image and I know that it has tons of JS beside Modernizr. But I want to know the way to do same things.