# background-image enlarge, crop but the content is static

Tags: html, css, background, resize

```
style{ background: url...}
<body>
  <div id = 'content'>
     BLABLABLABLABLBA
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to know how to set up the background image (in css) to be sure that if i crop the browser window, it will be readjust automatically. BUT the content need to be fix.

Thanks

Comment: In newer browsers you can use background-size. For older browsers you'll have no choice but to use a <img> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ESZJC/) that demonstrates the process to have both a fixed sized using `position:fixed` in a outer div while an inner div holding the image is using `background-size:contain`.

**EDIT:** Now an extra div is used to include any border requirements too!
**EDIT-2:** Updated jsFiddle with `:contain`, not `:cover` along with non-abstract image.

For old browsers such as **IE6-8** there are many plugins to choose from that allow the use of **CSS3 Styles**. This jQuery Plugin named [backgroundSize.js](http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/) is specifically for the use of `:cover` and `:contain` for `background-size` and is provided by SO member [Louis-Rémi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147089) if you need that option.

Answer (score 0):

An article on http://css-tricks.com/ called [perfect-full-page-background-image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) would be helpful in figuring out your problem. He gives you all of the different methods.

By the way, you just need keep the width of the #content a fixed width.