# IE8 Background Image not showing until I click & drag

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, background-image

This is the strangest IE error I have ever seen.

I have a background image set through this:

```
html {
    background: url('../res/bg_image.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The image shows up in Chrome & in Firefox but does not show in IE8.

BUT. If I click & drag anywhere on the screen, the image shows up (although it does not completely cover the screen). After this, I can click & drag anywhere else, even highlighting text, and the image stays up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix

Comment: I already saw that post & tried that fix but it didn't change anything.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support background-size, which is called out in that other thread.

Comment: It still does the same thing if I take out background-size

Comment: Please update your code and consider creating a fiddle.  There's no reason your vanilla CSS won't work with images in IE8 as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Background-size is not supported in IE8. That's probably your problem. 
http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: Same thing happens if I take out background-size attribute