# IE 8: background-size fix with -ms-filter

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

I found the same problem on Stackoverflow and a fix was posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9169401/1107123

I can make it work, but as soon I'm using it with PHP it does not.

Any ideas?

I also looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147089/1107123
But I have no idea how to implement it. The documentation is very vague :/

This does not work: (Inside PHP)

```
echo "<div style="filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img.gif',sizingMethod='scale'); -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img.gif',sizingMethod="scale');'></div>";
```

This works just fine: (HTML)

```
<div style="filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img.gif',sizingMethod='scale'); -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="img.gif",sizingMethod="scale");"></div>
```

Original Code:

```
echo        "<div class='sponsorImage' style='background-image:url($row[piclink]);'></div>";
```

How do I use the -ms-filter with this?

Comment: I think need to do something with "" and ' '

Answer (score 2):

It's not concern of PHP/RubyRails or whatever- it all about css  compatibility with browsers  - Try out this one http://pastebin.com/RZ0krHj0,

Comment: This is done in the CSS file, no?

I can't add a link from my DB in the CSS file afaik.

Comment: yes ofcorse! this is all about css only or you can give inline style also

Comment: But I have this variable "$row[piclink]" which adds the image-link for each div I have. I cannot have a specific image-link, since it gets the link from my DB.

Comment: could you please update your post with your original code ? so that we can understand better