# background-size in IE not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

hi i have looked to some questions here which have same subject 
as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107846/ie-8-background-size-fix-with-ms-filter) but didnt understand how he fixed it with html as he said.
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie)
but didnt understand how to implement it to work , 
anyway i have tried mine to test it but it doesnt seem to work.

```
    <style>
 .foo {
   font-size : 14px ;
   background-size: 832px 578px;
   background-image: url("al0-2.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 831px;
   height: 590px;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="al0-2.png",   
           sizingMethod="scale");
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='al0-2.png', 
           sizingMethod='scale')";
     }
   </style>
```

any help to fix this .
im wanting to let background-size works good in all IE also as FF do

EDIT>

my html code

```
      <div class="foo" ></div>
```

Comment: for the very beginning try to fix the quotes in this `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='al0-2.png',            sizingMethod='scale')"`

Comment: all ie versions as well.

Comment: edit with quotes , but still not working

Comment: All IE versions? WTH. Does that include IE5 and 6?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWUtm/2/) for you to experiment.

It works nicely in ie7/ff.

Although, note that in IE7, there will be 2 backgrounds : 1 from the background and 1 from the filter. You should remove the background one in someway (exemple : conditionnal comments).

In your code, if no image are displayed, maybe your image links are broken.

fiddle css :

```
#foo {
    border:2px solid red;

    font-size : 14px ;
    background-size: 832px 578px;
    background-image: url('/img/logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 831px;
    height: 590px;    


    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='/img/logo.png',
    sizingMethod='scale');

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
    src='/img/logo.png',
    sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: idont know how it works with you and not with me , i teid exactly yours but no , and tested it also in IE7 and the background is not full is little cutted in the right

Comment: im using this doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`)

Comment: Could you supply more code (html and css)? I fail to see your issue.