# CSS background-size not working in IE7/8

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

For some reason my background size is not working in IE 7&8. Can anyone tell me why. Also in the IE inspector, the background-size property is not showing up.

```
<a href="" class="twitter-custom-follow-button"></a>

.twitter-custom-follow-button {
  float: left;
  width: 96px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(../img/slices/btns/twitter_follow.png);
  background-size: 96px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: `background-size` is a CSS3 property, IE8- doesn't support it => http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but I thought I read somewhere that it DID work on IE7/8. Well I was wrong. this thread may be closed.

Comment: If you want to withdraw the question, the best way is to delete it yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `background-size` is a CSS3 property which [isn't supported](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) before IE9.

**However**, there is a thread which suggests a possible workaround:
[How do I make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 2):

IE 7/8 doesn't support the `background-size` property .. you will need to use javascript if you want the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

IE7/8 do not support `background-size`. It was only introduced in IE9.

If you want to support IE7/8 with this property, you'll need to use a polyfill script for it.

The only polyfill I know of that supports `background-size` is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) v2. Give it a go.  (it also adds support for several other CSS features that aren't in old IE versions)

Answer (score 0):

use this one code

```
 filter:progid:DXImageTransferform.microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')
```