# make css background size shrink using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to rework a bit of code to make a background image shrink when you scroll over it in the browser. The code I've been given currently does the opposite - it starts the background at 0  and makes if grow. Here's my code:

```
$('#item').css('background-size', (posish(12800)*100) + '%');
```

So when the browser window gets to 1280px, I want the background to shrink. And the posish function just passes a true or false value, here it is for reference:

```
function posish(pos) {

    pos-=19;
    if (scrolled-viewport/4 < pos) {
        return false;
    } else if (scrolled > pos+viewport/2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return (scrolled-viewport/4-pos)/(viewport/4);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I could reverse the initial function so the background starts at 100% and shrinks to 0% when posish is true - IE gets above 12800px? it currently does the opposite.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Just be aware that background size does work in IE8, although there are some hack/fix mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix

Comment: Thanks bcm. Luckily this site doesn't need to work in IE8, makes things more fun!!

Answer (score 1):

`(100-(posish(12800)*100)) + '%'`