# Background Not Stretching in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Our school computers use IE8, and there's nothing I can do to upgrade. How can I set this code to work with IE8?

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-image: url(at4.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-size: 100%; 
}
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `img` with one of the method detailed here: [Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) can be compatible with IE8+ or IE7+.

Otherwise it's not that important if your particular browser doesn't understand this or that (except if it's the most important aspect of your page, but it shouldn't be so for a background image). Progressive enhancement and graceful degradation are cool ;)

Answer (score 0):

background-size is not supported in IE8, you'll need to handle degrading gracefully.

http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

See [IE 8: background-size fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix)

Comment: is there a way to stretch it?