# IE8 ignores CSS styling

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix) solution about the background-size property. The problem is that every styling below this code stops working. It is just like IE ignores it.

[image]

```
#div {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/img.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='img/img.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale')"; 
}
```

Comment: @TylerH `-ms-filter` requires quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to hazard a guess that it doesn't like your filter parameters being on more than one line.

The reason for this is because it may not be interpreting the `}` correctly, thus causing the rest of the stylesheet to fail.

Try putting the entire `filter` string on a single line, and make sure that the `}` is on the line after it.

Comment: Well what do you know, another point for the "successful shots in the dark" ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#div {
background: transparent;
filter:
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=ie8-logo.png,sizingMethod='scale');
```

}

Please try like this "background: transparent"

Answer (score -1):

```
/* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

Comment: -stares blankly- How does changing the alpha opacity... emulate `background-size`?