# How to reduce size of image in IE 8

Tags: css

I applied this code but it is not working in IE 8

```
background: url("https://274a0e7125acf05720ef-7801faf96de03497e5e0b3dfa5691096.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rubbon.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
background-size: 65px 64px;
height: 130px;
width: 111px;
z-index: 1000;
display: block!important;
float: left;
margin-top: -113px;
margin-left: 2px;
```

Comment: background-size is not suppported in IE8, you'll need to use a smaller image - http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: Your answer should be here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving your support but i found the solution.we have to use filter.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>

    <style>
        .backgroundpic {
            background-image:none;
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
            src='img/home.jpg',
            sizingMethod='scale');
        }
    </style>

<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -2):

Add this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

to your HTMLs head tag, this might help in solving your problem.

Comment: No, no it won't. IE8 does not support background-size (full stop)