# Round Image Acting as Square

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image that is positioned over the top of a large anchor. The rounded image visually looks correct, however the image still acts as square on the DOM and is restricting access the anchor underneath.

How can I make it so that the rounded image does not have a square selectable area?

Here is a JS fiddle to show the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/jp81fp3u/1/
The entire blue square is an anchor, but notice even though the image is round, it still have square corners blocking the anchor. If the cursor is to close to the image the anchor does not enter hover state.

Code from JSFiddle:

```css
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.outer {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 8;
}

.outer a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9;  
}

.outer a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.circle {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
        <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="outer">
        <a href="#">
            anchor
        </a>
    </div>
    <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="circle" />
</div>
```

Comment: Give the anchor the same border-radius as the image.

Comment: which browser? works well on FF37 and Chrome 41

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jp81fp3u/3/)

Make the image a `div` with `border-radius` to half it's width so that it becomes a circle. Then use `background-image` to make the div into your 'image'

**HTML**

```
<!-- Change this -->
<img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="circle" />
<!-- To this -->
<div class="circle catpic"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
// Add this
.catpic {
    background-image: url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Note, however, that [IE8 does not support `background-size`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts), so you might have to have to use [a number of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4885145/2317532) to get around this.

Comment: The question is now : *"why does it work with a div and not an image tag..."*

Comment: Great, thanks. As i'm using Angular I extended to this: 
`<div class="circle" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg)'}">`

Answer (score 0):

Rounded image now has a circular selectable area.

```
.outer {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 8;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    top:25px;
    left:25px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

remove the height width from outer dive here is the link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manojrudra/jp81fp3u/2/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="outer">
        <a href="#">
        
        </a>
    </div>
    <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="" class="circle" />
</div>
```

css rule

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 8;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.outer a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9;  
}

.outer a:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.circle {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

Comment: My script fixed a broken link, but due to the licensing I cannot copy the code from jsfiddle. Please consider adding it as a snippet.