# Background Image is not fitted to screen in IE8+ versions

Tags: html, css

Hi I have an image which should be background image I have written a div and inside div I maintained some style for it and its working fine in Chrome and mozilla firefox , but its not working in IE8+ versions. below is the div that I used in my html.Do someone please respond to this.

```
<div style= "background:url(../portal/images/AWI_logo.png) no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;">
```

Comment: where your html code ?

Comment: I am new to stackover flow I am trying to insert my div but its not showing could you please helpme out .<div style= "background:url(../portal/images/AWI_logo.png) no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%;">

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885145/ie-8-background-size-fix

Comment: I tried it but its not working.

Comment: use `background-size: cover;` (works since IE9) - background-size is not supportet by IE8 ([see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size))

Comment: tried using background-size:cover but in Chrome and Mozilla the image is not showing fully. I have used the height and width as well. but no result

Answer (score 0):

You can use background-size: cover;

```
<h2>background-size: cover;</h2>
<div id="cover"></div>

div {
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-image: url(img.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#cover { background-size: cover; }
```

see sample [here](http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/NPMgem) you can learn more from csstricks [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)