# CSS Background Sizing Polyfill?

Tags: css, polyfills

Is there a polyfill to handle CSS Background Sizing in Safari 4 (iOS) and IE

Comment: Modernizr is just a feature detection script, it containes the HTML5 Shim and thats the only polyfill Modernizr ships with

Comment: See also [Good “background-size: cover” fallbacks/shims/tricks for cross-browser compatibility on DIVs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330733/good-background-size-cover-fallbacks-shims-tricks-for-cross-browser-compatibi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

could try this.

http://nooshu.com/jquery-plug-in-scalable-background-image

I'm in the process of looking as well.

Answer (score 1):

Allegedly this is a polyfill on GitHUb that enables CSS3 Background Size to work, but I'm still having issues figuring it out myself.

https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

Let me know if you get it to work. I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: Spent few hours trying to get this script to work. Some slight changes did the job:

<public:component lightWeight="true">
<public:attach event="onpropertychange" onevent="handlePropertychange()" />
<public:attach event="ondetach" onevent="restore()" />
<public:attach event="onresize" for="window" onevent="handleResize()" />
...
</public:component>

The last string was the key in my case. Xml document must have closing tags, otherwise nobody would give a dime for how browser handles that.

You may try it for yourself.

Comment: this tweak fixed the script for  me, thanks for this!