# extra space in table cell (IE6 and IE7)

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, cell

As title states, I have a problem with extra space in table cell, here is and example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pzcMH/60/ (go here http://jsfiddle.net/pzcMH/60/show/ if you want to see html page directly). You can see that table cell under 'footer wrapper' row is higher than 'center_wrapper' table (in IE6 and IE7) and I want it to be same height, like it is in all modern browsers.

After googling, I tried:

- adding cellspacing=0 and cellpadding=0
- removing extra new lines and spaces
- adding padding and margins with 0px
- ...

and nothing helped.

Off topic:

Someone will probably say that I shouldn't make layout, like in 2001, but I don't see a way to solve a problem with with extra wide elements not fitting in page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632505/fixed-layout-wide-content-tables) without table and it seems that I will manage to implement sticky footer with tables.

Another interesting bug of IE6/7 is that if I change 'footer_wrapper' row id to class (and modify css accordingly, of course) it stops working. Any ideas why?

thanks.

Comment: I played a little more and I took a different approach to achieve the effect that I needed - I wrapped footer in yet another div which aligns to bottom and although parent cell is wider, everything looks cool:
http://jsfiddle.net/pzcMH/62/.  
  
So my question remains unanswered, but I have a solution.