# CSS3 Background-Size EM with IE6, IE7, IE8 Support

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm hunting for a solution that provides IE6 - IE8 support for the following:

```
background-size: 10em 10em;
```

This would allow one to have dynamic sizing control over background images.

I'm okay with virtually any solution (HTC, JavaScript, CSS Hacks, etc.).

I do not want to stretch the background image across the entire container.  This can already be done with -vendor-background-size (using the *cover* value) and MS specific filters (IE6-8).

Comment: Dunno if you have found your solution, but this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie did it all for me.

Comment: Version 2 of [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) says it adds support for `background-size` to IE6-8. I haven't tried that specific feature yet, but the rest of CSS3Pie is pretty good, so it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of and seem to find is just:

```
background-size: 10em auto;
```

The auto to maintain the correct aspect ratio. Since the width is the important property of a background image define the width explicitly. 
The correct format for a background-size property is:

```
background-image: width height
```

*Personally* I would not use this as a scaling method. 
You should try to aim to be responsive. Loading different images for different resolutions, a very informative and interesting article by [Smashing Magazine](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-backgrounds/)

This would be a good start.

I hope this resolves your issue.