# filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader

Tags: css

I am writing some css that requires `background-size: 100% 100%`.

Unfortunately, as this is a css3 property, it is un supported in IE8 and below. However, I read about a hack, which I have tried using below:

```
#submit{
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( enabled='true' 
src='/images/btn.png', sizingMethod='scale'); 

  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( enabled='true' 
src='/images/btn.png', sizingMethod='scale')"; 

  background: url('/images/btn.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

`#submit` is the id of a submit button.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

This would scale it to the size of the whole page. But there is no real deal to ensure that background-size is working in IE. Even the MSDN Documentation tells that.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx#color

And btw: this is a possible duplicate of [How do I make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie)

Comment: I have tried what you posted and it doesn't seem to be working. I actually looked at the question you linked to and started from using the code posted in there. Also forgot to mention that I am trying to apply this to a submit button

Comment: so you want to add an image to a button or do you want to change the color of a button ?

Comment: The image is used as the background of the button.   `background: url('/images/btn.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;` Works fine in IE9. The filters however doesn't stretch the background image in IE8 and below

Comment: yeah thats bad, background-size is supported by IE9 only :(

Comment: Although I find it quite odd that the filters didn't work on the button. I haven't tried using it on anything else though.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to avoid AlphaImageLoader completely and use gracefully degrading PNG8 instead, which are fine in IE. If you absolutely need AlphaImageLoader, use the underscore hack _filter as to not penalize your IE7+ users.
Please check this link for your reference. https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#no_filters=