# Change width of background-image?

Tags: css

I tried to change the width but it only changes the width of the div.
How can I change the width of the image using css?

```
#photoTable {
    background-image: url("Assets/Images/FrontImages/partyPhoto.jpg");
    height: 628px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 704px;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that in pure CSS, isn't editing the actual image an option?

Comment: Not without changing the markup anyway, is that an option?

Comment: @mattytommo yes it is. But I am asking whether is a solution without editing the actual image

Comment: Ah okay, cross browser or IE9 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `background-size` property.  You can set it either to a width and height, `cover` or `contain`.  `100% 100%` might be closest to what you want, though.

```
#photoTable {
    background-image: url("Assets/Images/FrontImages/partyPhoto.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 628px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 704px;
}
```

Doesn't work in IE 8 or below.

Comment: For getting this to work in IE 8 and below, see the highest-voted (not accepted) answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie