# Background image size is not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css, background

my html code

```
<div id="content_main"></div>
```

css

```
        #content_main
{
    width:1024px;
    height:150px;
    background:url('../images/Orange.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:1024px 150px;
    -moz-background-size: 1024px 150px;
    -o-background-size: 1024px 150px;
}
```

background-size is not working in IE8,How to fix this problem,I dont have any idea,Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 does not support background-image options.  You can use the [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts) website to see browser support matrices for various HTML5 features like `background-size`.  Alternatively, if IE8 support is required, you'll need to use an `<img>` tag set behind your `<div id="content_main">`

Follow @ahsan's recommendation to check out [this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2991623/527096) which contains some polyfill suggestions and an `ms-filter` work-around for `background-size` in IE8

Answer (score 0):

Please check this reference about background property:
 http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems

Answer (score 0):

```
#content_main{

width:1024px;
height:150px;
background:url('../images/Orange.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:1024px 150px;
-moz-background-size: 1024px 150px;
-o-background-size: 1024px 150px;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='images/Orange.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='images/Orange.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Stretch background image using CSS3 `background-size: cover;` and `background-size: contain;`, in IE8 too.

How to use it?

Upload `backgroundsize.min.htc` to your website, along with the `.htaccess` that will send the mime-type required by IE (Apache only — it's built in nginx, node and IIS).

Everywhere you use `background-size` in your CSS, add a reference to this file.

```
.selector { 
    background-size: cover;
    /* The url is relative to the document, not to the css file! */
    /* Prefer absolute urls to avoid confusion. */
    -ms-behavior: url(/backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

The elements styled this way should have a `position: relative;` or `position: fixed;` and a `z-index.` If not, they will be given a `position: relative;` and `z-index: 0;`.