# Best way to hack the background-size issue on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Could you please suggest the best way to hack the background-size issue with IE8 ?

Comment: Possibly the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reference for the "cross-browser" solution of `background-size`.

As far as I know, you can achieve it by following [THIS TUTORIAL link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), as you have no code to show us in your questions, so I can only recommend you to take a look on that link.

By the way, as it is mentioned, it will work fine if need to fill the whole screen ( or bigger elements ), and it will be buggy with small-size items.

But anyway, there is a solution to fix IE problem when dealing with sprites.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your issue is, but this CSS IE8 hack might be of some use. Any CSS within these brackets will only be read by IE8.

```
@media \0screen {
    /*put css tags here as normal*/
    div.example {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
}
```