# CSS heading 1 background image

Tags: css, background-image, html-heading

I have this image here I would like to have as my background image for `h1` http://inauguralseason.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/wehavelaunched.png

My problem is how do I get the part to the left to appear? Here is my current CSS code

```
.homeBottom h1 {
    background-image: url("http://inauguralseason.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/wehavelaunched.png");
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 36px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 589px;
}
```

I would have thought use `margin-left:-50px` would have worked, but it did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify `height: 36px;` but your image is 86px high.  Change height to 86px and you'll see the whole thing.

If 36px is the correct height, you can change the background position instead.

`background-position: left bottom;`

Answer (score 0):

make these changes

```
.homeBottom {
position: relative;
}

.homeBottom h1 {
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
top: /* give as per required */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to `after` in your css

as like this

**HTML**

```
<h1>Hello testing page </h1>
```

**Css**

```
h1{
background:red;
  padding-left:20px;
  position:relative;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
}
h1:after{
content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:6px;
  top:18px;
  background:green;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
z-index:-1;
/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-65deg);
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-65deg);

}
```

demo http://tinkerbin.com/QTAO90R0

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) property (CSS3). In which you can set the `width` and `height` of the background-image. In your case, if you want to set the `height` of the background-image same as the `height` of the `h1` element then give:

```
background-size:100% 36px;
```

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/degmc/1/).

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353808/1577396) for making this property work in older versions of IE too.