# background-size property not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

IE-8 is not supporting the property background-size:cover; Anybody out there who knows how to implement this property in IE-8!

Looking for IE-8 hacks or HTML5 tips for IE-8 ;)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an IE filter, for IE 5.5+, which you can apply:

```
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

However, this scales the entire image to fit in the allocated area. So if your using a sprite, this may cause issues.

Specification: [AlphaImageLoader Filter @microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

source : [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353808/1577396)