# IE8 Background-size issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, parallax

I'm currently building a parallax site, it works on all browsers apart from the exception of IE8 due to using background-size.

I have tried ms filters just wondering if anyone else has a solution.

```
section {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow-x: hidden;
z-index: 0;

}

.parallax__one {
background: url("../Images/parallex__bg__1.png") 0px 0 no-repeat fixed;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(     src='../Images/parallex__bg__1.png', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='../Images/parallex__bg__1.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
    /* background size */
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

}

Comment: I found this great site called stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie

Comment: js.background won't work as it uses an image with a z-index but due to making a parallax effect it has to be set as a background in the css

Comment: @user1970409 faced with the same problem. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: I did end up fixing it i believe it was to do with widths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size` [does not work](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) in **IE8**

You will have to use something like this [polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill).

https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

---

### Instructions from the readme:

Upload `backgroundsize.min.htc` to your website, along with the `.htaccess` that will send the mime-type required by IE (Apache only — it's built in nginx, node and IIS).

Everywhere you use `background-size` in your CSS, add a reference to this file.

```
.selector { 
    background-size: cover;
    /* The url is relative to the document, not to the css file! */
    /* Prefer absolute urls to avoid confusion. */
    -ms-behavior: url(/backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

The elements styled this way should have a `position: relative;` or `position: fixed;` and a z-index. If not, they will be given a `position: relative;` and `z-index: 0;`.