# internet explorer background size issue

Tags: css

I have defined background as below:

```
body{
    background-image:url('taksi.jpg');
    background-size:100%; 
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Why these are different? (IE,Chrome) In as sense what is the problem?

ORDINARY CARE
[image: ordinary care]

AND IE :(
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie), background-size is an issue with IE.

The accepted workaround for this was:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Read more about this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6353808/84873).

Comment: According to [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size) background-size should work in Internet Explorer 9. Have you tried using the syntax background-size:100%, 100%; to see if that works?