# How to get buttons and anchors to work inside element with AlphaImageLoader Filter?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, size

In order to apply size to a background image in IE 8, I followed the accepted answer to this question [How do I make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie)

However, the anchors and buttons placed in the division does not work in IE 8.  Can someone please recommend a simple solution to this problem?

```
<!-- Here is my HTML !-->
<div id="masthead">
<div class="inner_masthead_inner_wrapper">


    <h1>HEADLINE</h1>
    <p>Sales copy</p>
    <h2>Give it a try, it's free!</h2>

    <button type="button" class="btn fbLoginBtn" onClick="FB.login();">Login with Facebook</button>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Here is my CSS !-->


#masthead{
background: url(../images/social-media-marketing-tool.jpg) no-repeat #000;
background-size: 100% 100%;

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/social-media-marketing-tool.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/social-media-marketing-tool.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale')';
}
```