# Background-size 100% not working in IE8 and IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have an empty div which contain a background image that is bigger than the size of the container. I fix this one by `background-image` property with the value (100% 100%). That's fine until you open the example in IE8 and IE7. Any solutions for that, even a javascript script or jquery plugin?

i.e: http://jsbin.com/imirer/1/edit

i.e: http://jsfiddle.net/bPTzE/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    /* an example width for responsive perpose */
    width: 500px;
}

.background {
    height: 27px;
    background: url("http://s18.postimage.org/jhbol7zu1/image.png") no-repeat scroll 100% 100% transparent;

    /* not working in IE8 and IE7 */
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: The background-size property is not supported by IE7-8, see : http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: I think this is the same issue :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie

Comment: Why do you use div inside of div to set a background? Hope you are aware it doesn't make any sense what so ever?

Comment: i made the container div just for and example of a small device MarcinWolny

Comment: i know that is not supported darma, but i need some JS solution for that

Comment: the same issue solution didn't work for me Aurélien Grimpard, and you can test that

Comment: there is a [background-size polyfill for IE8](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since background-size is CSS3 specific which is not supported to IE you have to do something like this for it to work in IE

set your html and body to

```
html {overflow-y:hidden}
body {overflow-y:auto}
```

wrap the image you want fullscreened with a div #page-background

```
#page-background {position:absolute; z-index:-1}
```

then put this in your html file

```
<div id="page-background">
  <img src="/path/to/your/image" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
```

** you will have to use some sort of reset to remove the margins and paddings, something like this

```
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

background-size not supported by ie7 and ie8.

the alternative way you can use put 'tag' in div tag and add width 100% to it. It is full scalable.

try this code:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://s18.postimage.org/jhbol7zu1/image.png" width="100%" />
</div>
```

or

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://s18.postimage.org/jhbol7zu1/image.png" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.container img {
     width:100%
 }
```

Comment: can you reexplain that in more details?