# background-size solutions for IE7

Tags: jquery, css

Good day to you guys

I am trying to find a way to fit this image on my div..My page are designed responsive(RWD).

The size of the image is 340x25 pixels and on CSS i did this

```
#mydiv{
 background:url('myimage.png') repeat-y;
 background-size:1px 100%;
}
```

which works on chrome and FF but not on IE7.

Is there any possible solutions for this?I already tried this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

But it only made the image fit on the whole div which is not my target outcome..
 •what I want to do is make the image 1pixel height and 100% width then use this image to repeat along y (repeat-y) ..is it possible?

Comment: IE7 is too old and rarely-used to deserve such efforts. Consider using graceful degradation if you care about IE7 users.

Comment: lol not me actualy my client wants it .. I know its too old and its causing me head aches hahaha... anyway thanks .. I found a way to fix the issue tho by editing the image itself caused me 3 hrs to fix it pixel by pixe X_X

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background-size 100% not working in IE8 and IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705025/background-size-100-not-working-in-ie8-and-ie7)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of different techniques you can try:

- http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Some of them even work for IE7+

Comment: how ever I don't find my desired target scale down to 1px height then stretch to 100% width do you have any solutions for that? so I could repeat the image along y(repeat-y)?