# Need to stretch the image used on a Input tag so that it works on IE7 & IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I basically need to use a fancy background image for my input type text.

I have the following **HTML**

```
<form id="search" class="" autocomplete="off">
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" class="myclass" name="q" />
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my **CSS**

```
#search .myclass {
    font-family: arial;
    height: 30px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url('/images/myimage.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Now this works perfectly on other browsers except for IE7 and IE8.

Please advice on this.

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705025/background-size-100-not-working-in-ie8-and-ie7

Comment: @DamianFrizzi Already tried that. It uses <b>img</b> tag and not <b>input</b>. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't think this makes any differences.. Posted an answer which you could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this IE filter to scale the image up to it's container:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='/images/myimage.png',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='/images/myimage.png',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```