# Can't stretch 100% div background image in css for IE8

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for top section of a website that will not stretch all the way across for Internet Explorer 8. have looked into many solutions but not one worked for me. Thanks in advance.

```
  <div id="header_combined">
  <img  align="left"  src="/1.images/others/logo/logo4.gif" alt="my logo"  />
  My site

  <strong>  Ltd.</strong>
  <p>"Some more text here"</p>
  </div>
```

CSS

```css
 #header_combined {

 background-size: 100%;
 Width:100%;
 float:left;
 font-size: 300%; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;color: #E1012F; text-align:left ;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; vertical-align:middle;
    text-shadow: white 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em
 padding-left:15em;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-image:url('/1.images/others/logo/combined logo2.jpg');

 }
 #header_combined strong {
 color: black;
 text-shadow: white 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    }
 #header_combined p {
 color: red;
 font-size: 0.3em;
 font-style:italic;
    }
```

Comment: `background-size` doesn't support IE8.

Comment: can you show your screenshot here..

Comment: Check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705025/background-size-100-not-working-in-ie8-and-ie7

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make background-size work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 2):

That's because `background-size` is a CSS3 property which [isn't supported](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) before IE9.

**However**, there is a thread which suggests a possible workaround:
[How do I make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie)

You try top set `alpha filter` property:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

[There is a nice discussion on this problem](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/background-size-and-ie8/)

Answer (score 0):

What logo image you want to stretch?

Try

```
.img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The image I want to extend across the screen is called "combined logo2.jpg" it is about 800x100 px. Won't the above extend every image in my website by 100%?

Comment: Not every image. note the "." in front of the name. It indicates a class, so every element with the class "img" :) However the OP didn't use a class img.

Comment: It only fixed my image stretch problem. But now all my page is pushed up, because of position:fixed and have trouble positioning logo and text on the background image.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

> #header_combined img { width:100%; }

Comment: That stretches the logo, not the background image.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
    .bg {
    background-position: left center;
    height: 102%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<img class="bg" src="artist-bg4.jpg" alt="">
```

add html code below `<body>` tag

Comment: I have two images. One logo and one strip that I would like to stretch 100%. then i would like the logo and writing to sit on top of the stretched strip.

Comment: above code helps you to set bg and then you can place logo and writing on it.
for Strip you can use property: 

background-repeat: { repeat | repeat-x | repeat-y | no-repeat | inherit } ;

Comment: The background image is a horizontal strip, therefore don't need it to be height:102%.

Comment: That worked a treat. thanks. had to remove position :fixed and adjust the height of the strip.

Comment: It only fixed my image stretch problem. But now all my page is pushed up, because of position:fixed and have trouble positioning logo and text on the background image.