# Setting a divs background image to fit its size?

Tags: image, css

I have a `<div>` with a background Image.

The `<div>` size may change over the time.

Is it possible setting the Divs Background image to fit the `<div>` size?

Lets say I have a div which is `400x400` and an Image which is `1000x1000`, is it possible to shrink the image to `400x400` and therefore fit the `<div>` size?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you'd like to use CSS3, you can do it pretty simply using **[background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)**, like so:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

It is supported by all major browsers (including IE9+). If you'd like to get it working in IE8 and before, check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie).

Comment: any way to do it in css 2.1?

Comment: @kfirba I believe IE9+ supports background-size, and I'm sure there are work-arounds to get it working in IE8 and before if you need it :)

Answer (score 26):

Use `background-size` for that purpose:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

More on:

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 17):

Use [`background-size`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) property to achieve that. You should choose between `cover`, `contain` and `100%` - depending on what exactly you'd like to get.

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: cover and contain were the things I didn't know, thank you for being more detailed than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve this with the background-size property, which is now supported by most browsers.

To scale the background image to fit inside the div:

```
background-size: contain;
```

To scale the background image to cover the whole div:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this as it can also act as responsive. :

```
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS3 background-size property for this.

```
.header .logo {
background-size: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your css to this

```
img {
    max-width:100%,
    max-height100%
}
```

Comment: that's exactly the problem, I don't want to use an image I want to use a Div with BG image

Comment: Ok, I thought you were using an image inside the div. You should use the background-size property then.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add a solution for IE8 and below (as low as IE5.5 I think), which cannot use `background-size`

```
div{
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=
'/path/to/img.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work but will not keep the image aspect ratio:

```
 background-size: 100% 100%;
```