# Background-size IE work around issue, duplicates image?

Tags: internet-explorer, duplicates, css

I've been working on getting my site optimized for IE8 and older, and I've been using a lot of Background-size in the css to adjust the images which have messed up the sizes in IE...

I got the [IE (filter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie) workaround to work, however my issue is that, now the image appears twice on top of eachother, - (before and after the work around). My css is as follows:

```
#kompetancer table tr td #os_icon {
background: url(images/os_icon.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
position: absolute;
background-size: contain;
-webkit-background-size:contain;
-moz-background-size:contain;
-o-background-size:contain;
-ms-background-size:contain;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/os_icon.png', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/os_icon.png', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JS polyfill for IE8, like [**background-size-polyfill**](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill)
 :-)