# Weird Behaviour in HTML Page

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a Web Application and I am experiencing a weird behavior from my app.

Basically, I set a `background-image` and the website `width` continues passed the image `length`.

Here's a printscreen:

[image]

What can I do to correct this?

I'm setting the background with this line:

```
<header style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(<?php echo base_url('assets/pagina_voluntario.jpg');?>);">
        <div class="header-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: What is the code that you have written?

Comment: Share with us the code you've written so we can see what you've done.

Comment: Maybe this helps `background-size: url("...") cover` and here is a site about your question https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of `background-image` is to display the image once at it's normal size. If the viewport ends up being larger than the background image, the image will not scale or repeat.

This can be fixed though with `background-size: cover` which makes the background "cover" the entire space without distorting the proportions of the background image.

So you would set the size of your background-image like this:

```
background-image: url(http://...);
background-size: cover;
```

Not all browsers support the cover property in CSS, (legacy IE and older Safari versions, for example) but I keep coming back to a fallback method you can add in front of the modern (and likely more efficient) `cover` approach so it doesn't completely fail on older browsers:

```
background: url(img2x.jpg) 0% 0%/100%;
```

(see the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845481/can-i-implement-a-css-only-fallback-for-background-size))