# input background image oversized in IE8

Tags: image, input, internet-explorer-8, background

I have an issue with an input background image that seems to be getting oversizes when opening in IE8 (this does not happens in IE10 or chrome).

This is the code for the input:

`<input class="search rounded" id="searchText" style="background: url(/cat/Images/search-icon-th.png) no-repeat 4% 50%; backgroundsize: 16px;" placeholder="Search" jQuery19107063960315369351="31"/>`

And the images to show the difference between Chrome and IE8

Chrome
http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/9963/q3cb.png

IE8
http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/5109/0z49.png

So, my question is how i fix this behavior in IE8?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the CSS look like?

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your code.

I would add something like this:

HTML:

```
<img id="fix" src="ImageLink" />
```

CSS:

```
#fix {
width: 100%;
height: 100;
}
```

That should make your image the size of the user's webpage.

Comment: I got my code fixed, however the one you posted does not seems to fit my needs.

Comment: I have been researching and found that background-size is not support by IE8, so I tried applying the filter as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie, however has not been able to make it work.