# CSS 'background-size' property - Cross-Browser Solution?

Tags: background, cross-browser, compatibility, css

I have an element that uses this css:

```
.my-box {
padding-left:50px;
background-image:url('images/img01.png');
background-size:20px;
height:20px;
}
```

My problem: in browsers like Internet Explorer, the 'background-size' property doesn't work. Is there a solution either through JavaScript, jQuery or CSS to make this work without having to put a physical <img> tag in the markup?

Comment: background-size: cover; :)

Comment: But I don't want the img01.png to cover the contents of the box. I want it to be 20px in size in my box. The 'background-size' property doesn't work at all in Internet Explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make background-size work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this polyfill. Maybe fill your issue. An IE behavior adding support for background-size: cover; and background-size: contain; to IE8.

**How to use it?**

Everywhere you use background-size: cover; or background-size: contain; in your CSS, add a reference to this file. `backgroundsize.min.htc`

```
.selector { 
    background-size: cover;
    /* The url is relative to the document, not to the css file! */
    /* Prefer absolute urls to avoid confusion. */
    -ms-behavior: url(/backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```

See here: [background-size polyfill github repo and further information](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill)

Comment: Looks very useful, but do you know if it supports `background-size: XXpx` because that is what I would like?

Comment: @JasonLipo Values other than cover or contain in background-size aren't supported.

Comment: @JasonLipo See this link. This is what you want exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6353808/1121982

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I should be able to use this fix to get it working.

Answer (score 3):

**Background will fill selector without scaling**

```
.background-size-cover {
  background: url('+$image_path+') no-repeat center top; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="+$image_path+", sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="+$image_path+", sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

**Background will be sized (scaled) to full selector height**

```
.background-size-full-height {
  background: url('+$image_path+') no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
  -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
  -o-background-size: auto 100%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```