# How can I use an <img> element as a background image with z-index?

Tags: html, css

I am using an image (in an `<img>` tag) as a background.  I want it to always be the furthest back object. But my paragraph isn't showing up because it is covered up by the image.

I know it has something to do with the z-index, but I can't get it working.

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html>

    <head>
    <title>2013 YourFantasyFootball</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<img src="images/final2.gif" class="stretch" alt="" />
<p>This is the first paragraph in the body of your new HTML file!</p>
asdfas
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: -1; /* Ensure div tag stays behind content; -999 might work, too. */
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
}

p {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `background-image` in the CSS?

Comment: because I won't be able to get it to stretch in all browsers

Comment: Give p a z-index greater than .stretch

Comment: I guess `background-size` isn't in old IEs. Still - why do you want to stretch it? That usually looks awful.

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: I'd recommend using backstretch.js to take care of that background image for you. It'll preserve the aspect ratio!

Comment: Do you want the image (background) to have the same width as the viewport (screen) or some other block level parent container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the image should be fixed, not the body.

```
body,html {
    height: 100%; 
}

.stretch {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xYqsT/

Comment: `position: absolute` would also work, depends on the desired effect, in this case the OP wants a fixed background.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph or content in front if it needs to have `position: relative`, otherwise anything with a z-index takes precedence.

Comment: I want to just fix it for the background image so I don't have to keep applying position relative to all future elements

Comment: @stackover The `z-index` property is meaningless unless you set it's `position` property.

Comment: so how would I set the background image to always be the furthest back?

Comment: @stackover: you can't, without setting other things to be further forward than the background image. As I suggest in my answer, your best bet (aside from just not worrying about `background-size` in IE 8) is to wrap all your other page content in an element with a z-index higher than your background `<img>` tag.

Comment: If you insist on using an `img` or another element in place of a `background-image` on the body, then you should also wrap your content in a `div` or another container so you only need to set `position: relative` on that container and all of the children show up correctly. Obviously a `background-image` on the body would be the best option here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure CSS, yes even for ancient browsers. This should cover IE5.5+:

```
body {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    background-image:url('images/final2.gif');
    background-size:cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/final2.gif',sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

The filter is for IE8-. [Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie), and [original spec found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**EDIT**

Aspect ratio not preserved using the filter ... very true, it does not scale preserving ratio the same way that `background-size:cover;` does. This is a very good article, though, about different methods to use:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

They provide multiple CSS-only, as well as jQuery, methods. One is bound to provide what you want.

Comment: The problem is the `filter` scales the image horribly and doesn't preserver the aspect ratio

Comment: very true. updated my answer with a link to an article that describes multiple methods, hopefully one will be the answer he wants. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't recommend highly enough using [backstretch.js](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/). I've used it for a lot of projects as there is no real solution to preserving aspect ratio of an image in CSS. If you're only supporting IE9+ then by all means, PlantTheIdea's answer is the best. But for anyone that is coming here and needs to preserve aspect ration for IE8- and if they need to use an `<img>` instead of `background-image` then use this great little plugin.

You can use it as a total background with just one line:

```
$.backstretch('https://img.jpg');
```

Or you can set it as the background on any element:

```
$("#demo").backstretch("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg");
```

You can also pass multiple images into the function and other parameters to create slideshows etc.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/gV5Qy/)**

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the image as a background-image

```
body {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background: url('images/final2.gif') repeat;
}
```

you can use background-size to size the image appropriately (stretching it to 100%)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pop all your page content inside an element (or several elements), and give them a `z-index` higher than your background `<img>`.

E.g.

#### HTML

```
<body>
<img src="images/final2.gif" class="stretch" alt="" />
<main>
    <p>This is the first paragraph in the body of your new HTML file!</p>
    <!-- All page content goes in here. -->
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
main {
    position:relative;/* So that it behaves as if it were position:static, but still gets a z-index */
    z-index: 1;
}
```