# Responsive full screen background. How to make it work with FF and IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, background-image

I'm having issues with the following placeholder background:

```
http://192.154.143.220/~capeannapparel/
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVXx8/

It has to be responsive and scale according to the browser window. It works in Chrome and FF but not IE.

I know IE has problems with background-size: cover; I was wondering what the best way is to make it work for IE? I tried various snippets of code on the web like:

filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/Background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/Background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";

but that didn't make a difference. Do I have to use jquery or something more complex or can this be done with CSS?

If anyone has any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make background-size work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie)

Comment: Thanks, but the filter code still doesn't work for me. IE shows a big gap at the bottom of the image and a scroll bar. Same with all the other bits of codes that have been posted in that thread.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: Version 11. Tried playing with it in developer mode but it still shows a scrollbar and a big grey box on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

try an if only IE stylesheet and add the following...

```
 background-size:auto 100%;
 overflow: auto;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it still won't budge. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it and it should work in all browsers:

```
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-ms-content-zooming: none;
background-size: cover;
```