# background-size in percentage IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I need to set up background-size in percentage let's say for example 50% of width of the element.

```
background-size: 50%;
```

I know that there are ways to make background-size cover or contain in IE8, but is there any way how to make it work with percentage in IE8.

Comment: What is your actual problem `background-size:50%;` is correct syntax

Comment: It is, but it doesn't work in IE8. I need to make it work in IE8 too.

Comment: You'll need either IE filters or JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie

Comment: But IE filters and JS works only for contain and cover background-size. I need a percentage value in background-size.

Comment: Not a duplicate. That answer deals with a polyfill that only supports "cover" and "contain", not percentages.