# how to background image fixed in ipad and iphone not scrolling with postion fixed

Tags: css

how to background image fixed  in Ipad and iphone some problem with postion fixed

demo83.com/helm/ << see in chrome parallax effect perfect but iphone and ipad problem

Comment: show me your parents css code for `.header_bg`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: The question linked above by @moo2u2 has the answer. [Here is an example for you](http://jsbin.com/runenaweqeyi/1/edit), it works in IE8 fine with that filter.

Comment: misterMan sam i'm useing but not showing image 100% in IE 8 but all browser is working properly

Comment: You are using `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='YOUR IMAGE HERE',
sizingMethod='scale');`? Could you add what you have now into your question?

Comment: You see i'm using your code

Comment: IE 8 not showing background image 100% im using filter but not working IE 8 you check it http://demo83.com/marks/

Comment: Try putting the full URL in the filter src - `http://demo83.com/marks/wp-content/themes/marks/images/header_bg.jpg`

Comment: hmmmmm THanks mistermanSam this is working :)

Comment: Excellent, it should work without needing to specify the entire image url, so see if you can get it working with some variant of `images/header_bg.jpg` :)

Answer (score -1):

If your image cannot span the width of the screen on its own, and you aren't repeating the image, then it won't span the width of the page.

Comment: `background-size: 100%` (if browser supported) will stretch any background image 100%. Even if it is 1px x 1px.

Answer (score -1):

Use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` at the top of the document before `<html>`

Comment: This makes no difference, the problem is  `background-size` [is not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) in IE8.

Answer (score -1):

The property `background-size` is of CSS3. And support for this CSS3 property was introduced in Internet Explorer 9. So unfortunately IE8 does not support `background-size`.

You may find Javascript fixes or something but short answer is if you use CSS3 then look for newer browsers or read [solutions for this issue](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/how-to-enable-css3-features-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8).

Possible fixes:

- Use Javascript/jQuery to find width of div and apply image of that size.
- Use `<img>` it can easily be stretched to 100% width.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie). The *easiest* solution is to use `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='YOUR IMAGE HERE', sizingMethod='scale');`