# IE8 Background-size not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to fill that my image fits the size of the DIV. 
I already find that "background-size: contain" is not working for Internet Explorer 8.

Is there a possible workaround for my specific code.

```
    .thumb {
        /* Select a maximum height and width to allot for each thumbnail. Set margin size here as well. */
        height: 125px;
        width: 135px;
        /* Do not edit these properties. */
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

In my javascript:

```
            $('.thumb:' + place).css("background-image", 'url(' + entry.thumbnailURL + ')');
            $('.thumb:' + place).css("filter", 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=' + entry.thumbnailURL + ',sizingMethod='scale')');
            $('.thumb:' + place).css("-ms-filter", 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=' + entry.thumbnailURL + ',sizingMethod='scale')');
```

Comment: It's not supported in IE8. http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make background-size work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie)

Comment: I have updated my javascript source. With this code I get an 'Unexpected identifier'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an `Unexpected identifier` because of these two bits:

```
 ',sizingMethod='scale')');
```

You must change it to

```
',sizingMethod=\'scale\')');
```

or

```
',sizingMethod="scale")');
```