# background-size before IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have some simple CSS which uses the property `background-size` to force the background to fill the page.

```
body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: url("/img/bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This code breaks on Internet Explorer 8 and lower, due to the lack of support for the property `background-size`. Using [this polyfill code](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill), its possible to add IE8 support to this code. However, the code still breaks on IE7 and lower.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can used the [AlphaImageLoader Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms532969(v=vs.85)) to solve this issue.

Also, you can check this post, which is similar to your issue.
[How do I make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie)