# Stretch an image in a div background

Tags: css, background

I have a div with a background image - and I want it to stretch as the div itself stretches.

My CSS is like this:

```
.infobox-medium-text
{
    width: 473px;
    height: 208px;
    background: url(../../images/infobox/infobox-medium.png) top no-repeat;
    float:left;
}
```

where as a div receives the `.infobox-medium-text` class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only)

EDIT: If you want this technique to work on a `div` instead of the `body`, add `position: relative;` to the `div`'s css.

Comment: this is a background for a web site - I need just for one div.

Comment: Ah, right. Sorry about that. I would imagine that it should work with a `div` as well, if you use `position: relative` on your div.