# CSS or jQuery scalable background image with NO white space underneath when img height is less than window height

Tags: jquery, css, image, background, scalable

Oldie but goodie, I know. This question is asked so many times and yet I haven't had a definitive answer. Scalable background image, preferably CSS only, willing to use jQuery in support if it's a must. A problem I've run into a lot (i.e. with CSS3 background-image) is empty space underneath an image when it's height is less than the browser windows height.
(example: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageToBackgroundImage/)

Here's what I'd like to accomplish:

- Maintain aspect ratio
- Clip image height and width if browser window is smaller than image size
- Image centered on page so the clipping doesn't offset the flow of the page

Here are some examples illustrating these goals (though I think it can be done better):

- http://www.thakoon.com/collections/thakoon-addition/pre-fall-2011
- http://whatstheweather.net/weather/submit

Thank you,
Thank you,
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like this would have to be done with javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
selector {
  background: url(bgimage.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

but it has browser incompatibilities.

.
Alternative solutions will force you to use HTML.

Examples:

- [Stretch and scale a CSS image in the background - with CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only/1208392#1208392)
- http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm

Comment: Be careful though. The `background-size` property only works in Safari/Chrome and Opera. For FF you will need `-moz-background-size`.

Comment: This is one of the browser incompatibilities I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
#wallpaper {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0; z-index:0}
#wallpaper img {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
```

html:

```
<div id="wallpaper"><img src="bg.jpg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Was recommended Supersize by a friend- it was exactly what I was looking for! Used the core function instead of the slideshow version.
http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Using jQuery. IMG tag is set as the background image by using `position:absolute; z-indez:0;` As you resize the window the image will resize accordingly. Cross browser compatible.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var bgwidth = $(window).width(),
    bgheight= $(window).height();
    $('img').attr({width:bgwidth, height:bgheight});
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/LBvjR/

Comment: Doesn't maintain aspect ratio

Comment: @daniel Image aspect depends on how you resize your window. Image cannot have 100% width and height and still maintain aspect ratio. What happens if you resize your window to 100px width by 600px height. How can width be 100px and height be 100% and still maintain aspect. We are expanding the img to fit 100% width and height of the window without any space as per your request

Comment: I'd like the image to retain its original aspect ration and after a minimum size, start clipping the image. Here's an example of that, but clipping towards the top left: http://nooshu.com/explore/scalable-background/ I'd like to have it clip towards the center of the image. Possible?

Comment: @Daneil, To have it maintain aspect ratio as in your thakoon link about, we can set height to 100%. Width will vary. No need for javascript in this case.. Check http://jsfiddle.net/LBvjR/2/. This will make the image scale as the height of the window change and keep aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://github.com/weightshift/The-Personal-Page ?

It uses the [backstretch](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) jQuery plugin that does the job quite well.