# Stretch an image to fill width of browser window

Tags: html, css

I have an image, and I want the width to fill up the browser window, no matter the size of the window.

How do I do this in HTML and CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS or jQuery scalable background image with NO white space underneath when img height is less than window height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072750/css-or-jquery-scalable-background-image-with-no-white-space-underneath-when-img)

Answer (score 18):

You can add a div with width an height of 100%, also set image's width and height are 100%

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
</div>​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper, img{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbagdat/7j3mn8q1/4/)

Answer (score 8):

```
<img src="filename.jpg" alt="alt text" width="100%" />
```

This assumes that the image's container is as wide as the browser window.

Comment: this is not valid for HTML 5. In HTML5, value must be in pixels.

Comment: @sbagdat Interesting. I didn't know that. Any idea why percent was removed as an option?

Comment: probably when images are getting bigger, they are losing quality. here is the w3c link: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_img_width.asp

Comment: svg (vectorial) images don't lose quality.  It works for me in browsers/devices I tried

Answer (score 2):

You add the following `<meta>` element in the head of your HTML document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then you add

```
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
```

as a CSS rule for both the image and the container of the image. (It can also work for the image without having a container.)

And you add

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

to get rid of the margin around the image and/or container. This is how your image will fill the whole width of the screen, no matter what size the screen is.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="fixpixel">
    <img src="ImagePath" />
</div>​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS file

```
.fixpixel img{
height: auto;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin of the body element is set to a default of 8px, which is the space you are seeing which prevent the image to stretch the full width and height of the screen.

You can include

```
body {margin: 0px;}
```

to prevent this behavior, which I guess was put in place to prevent unstyled pages to present the content pushing to the edge of the page. It was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550467/why-is-there-a-default-margin-on-the-body-element/34550634).