# How do I redefine the origin of the window for createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) in JavaScript (chrome web browser)?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm getting started on javascript using the p5.js library and I noticed this: 
[canvas NOT positioned in top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSXxS.png)

When I create a canvas, it is at the origin in cartesian plane. But the origin is not at the top left corner of the window. Actually, the origin (0, 0) is at (8, 8) and the top left corner is at (-8, -8).
(Maybe) You can see this "offset" running the snippet.

So how do I relocate the origin (0, 0) to the top left corner? or
How do I relocate the created canvas to the top left corner?

(This happens in Chrome and in Edge, but works fine in Firefox. And I'm on Wwindows 10).

This didn't work: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Positioning-your-canvas

```js
function setup() {
  var cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(0, 0, 30, 30);
  console.log(mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <title>index</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you check doing an inspect-element on the white border? There are a lot of styles you inherit from the user-agent-stylesheet that could simply be applying a padding or something on your body around the canvas.

Comment: I only see this problem with the Stack Overflow snippet. I don't see this problem in the P5.js editor. Are you sure it's not the SO snippet system adding some styling?

Comment: thank for the tip, Josh. I'll use it the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550467/why-is-there-a-default-margin-on-the-body-element). To relocate, you could try styling the body:

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px
}
```

or assigning a [parent](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/parent) element to the canvas and styling that.

Comment: Well, it worked. The body had an 8px margin. Thanks :)