# full Background image Mouse Move Coverage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small script to tilt the background image when mouse is moving. I have tried 3 different images and no matter what size they are there is a white gap when the image moves.

the background image follows the mouse without issue. is just shows white gaps , I have tried setting the image in every what to no avail.

```js
$(function() {
  // Init
  var container = document.getElementById("container"),
    inner = document.getElementById("inner");
  // Mouse
  var mouse = {
    _x: 0,
    _y: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    updatePosition: function(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      this.x = e.clientX - this._x;
      this.y = (e.clientY - this._y) * -1;
    },
    setOrigin: function(e) {
      this._x = e.offsetLeft + Math.floor(e.offsetWidth / 2);
      this._y = e.offsetTop + Math.floor(e.offsetHeight / 2);
    },
    show: function() {
      return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
  };
  // Track the mouse position relative to the center of the container.
  mouse.setOrigin(container);
  //-----------------------------------------
  var counter = 0;
  var updateRate = 10;
  var isTimeToUpdate = function() {
    return counter++ % updateRate === 0;
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  var onMouseEnterHandler = function(event) {
    update(event);
  };
  var onMouseLeaveHandler = function() {
    inner.style = "";
  };
  var onMouseMoveHandler = function(event) {
    if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
      update(event);
    }
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  var update = function(event) {
    mouse.updatePosition(event);
    updateTransformStyle(
      (mouse.y / inner.offsetHeight / 2).toFixed(2),
      (mouse.x / inner.offsetWidth / 2).toFixed(2)
    );
  };
  var updateTransformStyle = function(x, y) {
    var style = "rotateX(" + x + "deg) rotateY(" + y + "deg)";
    inner.style.transform = style;
    inner.style.webkitTransform = style;
    inner.style.mozTransform = style;
    inner.style.msTransform = style;
    inner.style.oTransform = style;
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  container.onmouseenter = onMouseEnterHandler;
  container.onmouseleave = onMouseLeaveHandler;
  container.onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}


.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 50px;
  perspective: 50px;
}


.inner {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6909249-black-hd-background.jpg');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="inner" class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Xufox thanks for that I was actually following a tutorial from a site.

Comment: @Xufox I was talking about the type error I was following a tutorial here https://css-tricks.com/animate-a-container-on-mouse-over-using-perspective-and-transform/ and I dont know much about js thats why I put the () because it had them.

Comment: @Xufox what I am trying to accomplish is this background effect https://www.videinfra.com/   everything works but the image show what gaps on the side when moving mouse the image is not covering everything

Comment: But that’s just not the same syntax. You used `$(function(){`…`})`, they used `(function(`…`){`…`})(`…`)`. In this case `$(function(){`…`})` is guaranteed to work.

Comment: One part of the issue is that you need to set `margin: 0;` to `body` to remove the [default margins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34550467/4642212). Another part is that you may want to scale the image to make it bigger than 100% width and height. Then the `<div>` needs to be repositioned somehow to center it.

Comment: @Xufox I have tried all these things even used a 3000x3000 image  tried every property in css i know same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code updated from @Xufox's comments:

```js
$(function() {
  // Init
  var container = document.getElementById("container"),
    inner = document.getElementById("inner");
  // Mouse
  var mouse = {
    _x: 0,
    _y: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    updatePosition: function(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      this.x = e.clientX - this._x;
      this.y = (e.clientY - this._y) * -1;
    },
    setOrigin: function(e) {
      this._x = e.offsetLeft + Math.floor(e.offsetWidth / 2);
      this._y = e.offsetTop + Math.floor(e.offsetHeight / 2);
    },
    show: function() {
      return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
  };
  // Track the mouse position relative to the center of the container.
  mouse.setOrigin(container);
  //-----------------------------------------
  var counter = 0;
  var updateRate = 10;
  var isTimeToUpdate = function() {
    return counter++ % updateRate === 0;
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  var onMouseEnterHandler = function(event) {
    update(event);
  };
  var onMouseLeaveHandler = function() {
    inner.style = "";
  };
  var onMouseMoveHandler = function(event) {
    if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
      update(event);
    }
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  var update = function(event) {
    mouse.updatePosition(event);
    updateTransformStyle(
      (mouse.y / inner.offsetHeight / 2).toFixed(2),
      (mouse.x / inner.offsetWidth / 2).toFixed(2)
    );
  };
  var updateTransformStyle = function(x, y) {
    var style = "rotateX(" + x + "deg) rotateY(" + y + "deg)";
    inner.style.transform = style;
    inner.style.webkitTransform = style;
    inner.style.mozTransform = style;
    inner.style.msTransform = style;
    inner.style.oTransform = style;
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  container.onmouseenter = onMouseEnterHandler;
  container.onmouseleave = onMouseLeaveHandler;
  container.onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
});
```

```css
html, body {margin:0 ;padding:0}

body {
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}


.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 50px;
  perspective: 50px;
}


.inner {
  position: static;
  display: block;

  width: 120vw;
  height: 120vh;
  margin:-10vh 0 0 -10vw;
  transition:.5s;


  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6909249-black-hd-background.jpg');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  bbackground-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="inner" class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, is it possible to smooth out when mouse goes out of browser?

Comment: @Codi, yes it's possible e.g. with `transition` property. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the background picture won't help. Those gaps are caused by how your `div.inner` is rotated. Here is a simple graphical explanation:

[image]

Possible solutions:

1. Scale div when rotated. You'll need to scale by `(1 / cos(rotation_angle))`. But that is not very good approach. It will not look nice enough.
2. Scale `div.inner` once depending on maximum possible angle of rotation. Don't forget to shift it to the desired position with negative margins or `position: absolute`.

Here is an example of how it works, based on your code. Note, that it is not full working code, I just modified width and margin. To get exactly what you want you need to set scale and positioning by yourself.

```js
$(function() {
  // Init
  var container = document.getElementById("container"),
    inner = document.getElementById("inner");
  // Mouse
  var mouse = {
    _x: 0,
    _y: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    updatePosition: function(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      this.x = e.clientX - this._x;
      this.y = (e.clientY - this._y) * -1;
    },
    setOrigin: function(e) {
      this._x = e.offsetLeft + Math.floor(e.offsetWidth / 2);
      this._y = e.offsetTop + Math.floor(e.offsetHeight / 2);
    },
    show: function() {
      return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
  };
  // Track the mouse position relative to the center of the container.
  mouse.setOrigin(container);
  //-----------------------------------------
  var counter = 0;
  var updateRate = 10;
  var isTimeToUpdate = function() {
    return counter++ % updateRate === 0;
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  var onMouseEnterHandler = function(event) {
    update(event);
  };
  var onMouseLeaveHandler = function() {
    inner.style = "";
  };
  var onMouseMoveHandler = function(event) {
    if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
      update(event);
    }
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  var update = function(event) {
    mouse.updatePosition(event);
    updateTransformStyle(
      (mouse.y / inner.offsetHeight / 2).toFixed(2),
      (mouse.x / inner.offsetWidth / 2).toFixed(2)
    );
  };
  var updateTransformStyle = function(x, y) {
    var style = "rotateX(" + x + "deg) rotateY(" + y + "deg)";
    inner.style.transform = style;
    inner.style.webkitTransform = style;
    inner.style.mozTransform = style;
    inner.style.msTransform = style;
    inner.style.oTransform = style;
  };
  //-----------------------------------------
  container.onmouseenter = onMouseEnterHandler;
  container.onmouseleave = onMouseLeaveHandler;
  container.onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}


.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-perspective: 50px;
  perspective: 50px;
}


.inner {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: 130%; margin-left: -40px;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url('https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6909249-black-hd-background.jpg');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="inner" class="inner"></div>
</div>
```