# Margin white space in body tag

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, deployment, comboboxmodel

[image: it is inspecting body tag see there is some margin on top 8px but still there is some space there what is that]

also see this[image: if I add border then magically that goes what is happening]
it is inspecting body tag see there is some margin on top 8px but still there is some space there  what is that but if I add border then magically that goes what is happening
somebody pls explain this?

somebody pls explain this?

code is

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550467/why-is-there-a-default-margin-on-the-body-element ? Other than that, you MAY put `html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`.

Comment: no one really answered this why white space if it is not margin then what is it and it works fine if I add border

Comment: Try `html, body{box-sizing:border-box;}`- Without that your border will be put outside the element. 