# background-size:100% 100%; doesn't work properly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, background-image

I'm using an svg image as a background. I'm trying to use CSS3's `background-size: 100% 100%;` but it doesn't seem to work, even in browsers which should support it (like Chrome).

If you look at [this site](http://www.imadake.ca/) you'll see the `#special-post article` (to the right/below the food image) with a red banner-looking background. Notice that as you shrink the window down, the height of the background image drops to retain it's proportions, rather then stretching, as I would like.

EDIT:
I checked this on FireFox and it works correctly... so this appears to be a webkit issue.

EDIT:
I checked this on Safari and it works! So it looks like my problem is specific to Chrome.

[image]

(PS: I'm familiar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150163/stretch-and-scale-a-css-image-background-with-css-only) alternative solution, using an `img` tag, but I'd rather not use it.)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

Open your `.svg` file, find the `<svg>` tag at the beginning and add the following property inside it:

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

Source: http://www.yootheme.com/support/question/6801?order=modified

Comment: Awesome! I would upvote 10 times if I could. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this tip, i couldn't wrap my head arround what I was doing wrong.

Comment: I cannot believe this worked. Things like this never work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Chrome still has this bug & this answer fixes it!

Comment: Warning: this attrbute seems to be caseSenistive.

Comment: I was starting to doubt the world before I saw this answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
background-size: cover
```

Works across the board. Tested w/ Safari, Chrome, & FF.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't do what I'm trying to accomplish. `cover` scales UP the entire image proportionally to fill the space. I want the image to distort so that it fits the dimensions of the `article`.

Comment: In more concrete terms, I want all four points of the red background image to stay visible, just stretched/compressed to match the height of the `article`.

Comment: Consider using a PNG instead of an SVG. I know this is kind of lame advice, but it might just be the only practical way.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is a known bug in Chrome that is specific to svg background images. I'm running v 17.0.963.56, in case anyone cares, and you can track the bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110195).

Comment: It's not specific to SVG images. I'm having the same issue with a JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue in Chrome 39, but not in Firefox. I ran into it when scaling a background SVG like so:

```
background-image: url(bg.svg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: 1200px auto;
```

Even with exact on-the-pixel horizontal dimensions in the SVG I got a small gap. It worked when I didn't scale it:

```
background-size: auto auto;
```

Not much of a solution not to be able to scale your background, but still.

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks.