# background image displaying incorrectly when browser is narrow

Tags: html, css

On [this page](http://festivals.ie/) I have 2 background images:

(1) A blue sunburst that is set as a background image of `<html>`

```
html {
    background: url("BEhmxDlyFwihBhnuPwHL8VU1fr59VGeXflJlinXMr5q.svg") no-repeat fixed center center / 100% auto transparent;
    outline: 0 none !important;
}
```

(2) An image showing a crowd of arms in the air that appears at the bottom of every page. I use the [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) solution to make this stick to the bottom of each page

Everything works fine at normal browser widths, but once the browser width is below about 500px a white space starts appearing at the top:

[image]

and at the bottom

[image]

of every page. Previously I used

```
background-size: cover;
```

for the sunburst image, but this caused the website to crash the browser on iOS 6 (seriously), so I need to find a way to fix this without using this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white space is due to the browser positioning the image `center center` as defined in the CSS.

```
html {
    background: url(BEhmxDlyFwihBhnuPwHL8VU1fr59VGeXflJlinXMr5q.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    outline: 0!important;
}
```

I thought the solution would be just setting `background-size: 100% 100%` as the current setting of just `background-size: 100%;` is `100%` width and  *auto* height. But it's bugged in Chrome - [background-size:100% 100%; doesn't work properly in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334095/background-size100-100-doesnt-work-properly-in-chrome). There is a workaround answer on that question that might help.

However, if the `background-size: 100%;` is dropped for `width < 500px`, perhaps in one of your @media rules, then the background fills the page as expected. The rule is still required when the window is greater than the width of the image to stretch the image.

Comment: If something in CSS works in majority of the browsers, and if it is logical, then screw Chrome, I would use it even if it won't work, I won't build websites according to browsers.

Comment: But if it's a Webkit bug then it wouldn't work on Safari either. Not many iPhone users using something other than Safari or Chrome I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not opposed to a JS solution, you could try using [Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/).

Answer (score 0):

Set the background-size to something larger than 100%. I think 200-250% will cover that area.

```
background-size:220%;
```

One side effect this has is the fact that it causes slight lag due to the size.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Have this solution...

In this file...

http://festivals.ie/static/C5z61WeZeCfyTRbmu6lNPsxXxwhibmxExq6ADwtSPjh.css

On line no 793,

this code is there in the last part of that line...

```
html{background:url(BEhmxDlyFwihBhnuPwHL8VU1fr59VGeXflJlinXMr5q.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:100%;
outline:0!important;}
```

Add this property : background-position: 0px 0px;

Making the code:

```
 html{background:url(BEhmxDlyFwihBhnuPwHL8VU1fr59VGeXflJlinXMr5q.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:100%;
outline:0!important;
background-position: 0px 0px;}
```

And fyi, as andyb pointed out the white space is the image leaving its top position to be centered, thereby making it look like a white space starting to appear..

Hope you get the point.

Regards

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but with this solution the background will not extend to the bottom of the page when the window width is < 500px

Comment: well thats how the backgrounds work :P, and btw he can always repeat the background, if the width fall too short. 

Theres also one other option i'd like to mention.. viz. add the background size property as shown below...

    background-size:100% 100%;

Comment: ...continued.

This way the background will always try to fill the page to its brim, have just one drawback which is, the aspect ratio of the background will be distorted if the dimension on the window of the browser is not in multiples of the aspect ratio of the image... 

BUT since the OP is using SVG as the background, there's really not much of a difference.