# Resize svg image as background in chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I am using svg image as background and I am stretching SVG image through background-size. I want it to be strech only width wise. Its working perfectly fine in firefox, IE9 + but chrome. Please suggest me how i can achieve it.

```
.homecallouts ul li {
background-image: url('blue_arow_callout.svg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
width: 21%;
height: 42px;
```

see the jsbin code
http://jsbin.com/uvijuc/4/

when i resize in firefox only width stretch but in chrome both width and height are stretching. I want only width to stretch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [background-size:100% 100%; doesn't work properly in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334095/background-size100-100-doesnt-work-properly-in-chrome)

Answer (score 20):

Maybe adding preserveAspectRatio="none" to open  tag in the SVG file could help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="282.05px" height="61.974px" viewBox="286.287 26.514 282.05 61.974" enable-background="new 286.287 26.514 282.05 61.974"
     xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<polygon fill="#0063AF" points="538.337,26.514 286.287,26.514 316.287,57.5 286.287,88.488 538.337,88.488 568.337,57.5 "/>
</svg>
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/uvijuc/10/edit)

Comment: Ilya Streltsyn i love you...seriously you probably just saved my live, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 6):

I do not have enough reputation to upvote or comment, so only answering it again will work. I solved a similar case by just adding  preserveAspectRatio="none".

```
<svg
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
width="591.42859"
height="250.24918"
id="svg2"
version="1.1"
preserveAspectRatio="none"
inkscape:version="0.48.2 r9819"
sodipodi:docname="background.svg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use background-size.  What you need to do is have the following values for width, height and preserveAspectRatio in your SVG file.

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" viewBox="..." />
```

Note that in order for this to work, your SVG needs to have a valid viewBox as well.  Which it does appear to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Chrome bug. Regression, in fact.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113414

Comment: In may case, though, setting `preserveAspectRatio="none"` did help.

Answer (score 0):

I think technically chrome is correct on this one, you need to adjust your background-size values to what you actually want. Keeping them at 100% is forcing the aspect ratio to remain constant.

Comment: Would be helpful if your answer contained the code to make it the way the OP wants.

Comment: I have specified 42px hight and background-size height also 100% so why height is stretching. oh the other hand firefox is working what i desired.